# android How to stretch rows in the gridview to fill screen?

Tags: android, gridview, screen

I have simple GridView (with one column and six rows), that displays ImageView with TextView in the cell (I create adapter). How to stretch rows to fill entire screen height?? Now I have some space below cells...

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="150dp" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/left">
    <include layout="@layout/menu_grid"></include>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/right">
    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/image"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageMain" 
        android:layout_gravity="center">
    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

menu_grid.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<GridView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:padding="10dp" 
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp" 
    android:numColumns="1"
    android:columnWidth="100dp" 
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"></GridView>
```

item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" android:gravity="fill_horizontal">
<ImageView android:src="@drawable/icon"
    android:layout_height="70dp" android:id="@+id/imageIcon"
    android:layout_width="70dp" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"></ImageView>
<TextView android:id="@+id/textIcon" android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>
```

ImageAdapter.java

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
//....some code
//....

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view;
    if (convertView == null) {  
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)_context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

        TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textIcon);
        text.setText(labels[position]);

        ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageIcon);
        image.setImageResource(icons[position]);        

    } else {
        view = convertView;
    }

    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: Post your layout and/or code.

Answer (score 32):

As of what i understood, the question is- if i have 6 rows of data to be filled in the gridView, how can i make these 6 rows fill the whole screen, instead of showing 6 rows and some empty space under the last row.

To achieve this you must set minimum height of the gridView item layout (in your case its item.xml) to (height of the screen)/6, where 6 is the (no.of rows you have to fill). This minimum height can be set in the adapter you are using.

To find the height of the screen of the device:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

int width = metrics.widthPixels;
int height = metrics.heightPixels;
```

find these values in the Activity and make them public static and use them in the adapter, i had a problem in finding these values in the adapter class

then to set minimum height:

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
view.setMinimumHeight(GridViewActivity.height/6);
```

I tried this after seeing the post, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @androidmaniac how to put my RecyclerView 2x2 filled on the screen of the device?

Comment: Can you help me with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47438092/in-app-billing-connect-to-firebase-and-get-products) please?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. I'm trying to fill the full screen by cells of `Caldroid` calendar.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to increase the space between the lines You can use padding  it should work.
you can set padding through xml or programmatically based on your requirement.

```
// this you can set inside your view.
android:paddingLeft="5px"
android:paddingRight="5px"
android:paddingTop="10px"
android:paddingBottom="10px"

// this you can set to your any widgets like TextView/Layouts/Buttons etc..
setPadding(top, left, bottom, right);
```

Answer (score 0):

Extend a layout say Framelayout then override the `onMeasure` method.

```
public class CameraView extends FrameLayout 

public TextView titleView;

public CameraView(Context context,AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs)
    titleView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.titleView);
}


@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
}
}
```

You can then use this view in your BaseAdapter and set the `layout_width` and `layout_height`  to `match_parent`

Answer (score -1):

I hope I am understanding you correctly, if so it is as easy as changing your `GridView` to `fill_parent instead` of `wrap_content`.

Change

```
<GridView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

to

```
<GridView android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

If this is not the case then it is probably the layout height on the `LinearLayout` of the item.xml that you want to modify.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesnt work:( I just want to increase the space between the lines to fill the screen (stretch rows, not columns).. I will try with layout height:)