# Android AT_MOST hack - how does it work?

Tags: android, measurement

I found an answer to my question in this thead: [android How to stretch rows in the gridview to fill screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067449/android-how-to-stretch-rows-in-the-gridview-to-fill-screen)

Indeed I do not understand how the following works:

```
@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    // HACK! TAKE THAT ANDROID!
    if (isExpanded())
    {
        // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
        // But do not use the highest 2 bits of this integer; those are
        // reserved for the MeasureSpec mode.
        int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);
```

Is there somewhere an explanation, about why the bits where shifted, and how AT_MOST works?
Shouldn't there be maximum size value, together with the AT_MOST flag?

Comment: Did you try this? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.MeasureSpec.html for AT_MOST

Comment: "The child can be as large as it wants up to the specified size" - it is not clear to me where to specify the size. Are you able to explain, where to specify the AT_MOST size, and how the shifting of those 2 bits fits within this specification?

Comment: "MeasureSpecs are implemented as ints to reduce object allocation. This class is provided to pack and unpack the <size, mode> tuple into the int." Size is the first parameter and mode the second to `makeMeasureSpec`.  The shift occurs because it looks like they get stuffed into a single int.  Shifting off two because the mode requires the last two.